# ssrs piechart format to 2 decimal places

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the following dataset for my ssrs report :

```
 Year Month Sales1 Sales2
  2013  3     29.22   29.99
```

I want to show Sales1 & Sales2 in a pie chart.
I want to format it to show only 1 decimal place.

I right click on the  chart,
select series label properties, 
Under Number I select the decimal formatting needed.

I see in the graph that only sales1 is getting formatted and sales2 doesnt .
example : I see 29.2 for Sales1  , but for sales2 I still see 29.99.
Is there an efficient way to format both the values in a pie chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for my question myself :-).

The above procedure I used to format the values , formats only the first value. It should technically 
format all the values used. It kind of is a bug on SSRS.

Checking the Properties for each of the values Sales1 and Sales2 showed that ,
the format property was not set for Sales2. So , this part has to be done manually.

So I set the format manually and the solution works !!

Hope it helps someone who come across the same problem .